# What’s with the “dead” characters at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, v-for-vendetta

Near the end of V for Vendetta, while the building is exploding, you see people pulling off their masks to watch it explode.  During this scene you see some characters that have been previously said to be dead.

Here are the character’s I’m talking about:

- the girl  vandal (shown to be shot)
- the actress (shown killed in the experiments or whatever)
- Gordon Deitrich (the talk show host said by V to have been shot)

Was this meant to say that these characters are still alive, or was there a different intent?

Comment: Aye, this confused me for years as it seems implied that the girl's shooting is what sparked people to show up to the bombing

Comment: If you watch closely, the young girl isn't actually shot, that's part of Finch's prediction. As for Gordon and the woman, I don't know.

Comment: Actually the idea was true story. Guy Fawkes, or Guido Fawkes, was a conspirator in the Gunpowder Plot. His legacy reminds us that people need not be afraid of their government, but governments should fear the people. Remember, remember, the 5th of November. He die with broken neck before the execution.31 January 1606

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would consider this a symbolic gesture meant to remind the viewer that the outcome of the movie was not possible without their sacrifices. They all wore V's mask and that symbolizes that we can all be V and that what he stood for cannot die because we all stand for it. Good ideas don't die.

Comment: or they were too cheap to hire more extras (joke)

Comment: Kinda feel like they should've made it more "spiritual", instead of them physically being there. Causes confusion instead of clarity about the overall moral of the story

Comment: I feel making it more spiritual would elude the feel of the movie and would distract. To be specific, I think it would hint to the paranormal in a more obvious way than them physically being there, and that would alienate the audience. (if they, for example, appeared as ghosts or apparitions there). It wouldn't be fitting.

Comment: In the original novel Evey is about to pull the mask off V to see who it could be and we see lots of potential persons before it settles on her own face where she then understands that she is to continue as V. 

This doesn't happen in the film so it looks like they interpreted this or added some meaning with the dead characters indicating that they are all V and all struggled for the same purpose. This is similar to @Bernard's answer I guess but I thought it is worth mentioning the key thing missing from the novel at the end.

Answer (score 8):

source : [V for Vendetta Explained](https://www.thisisbarry.com/film/v-for-vendetta-2006-movie-vs-graphic-novel-explained/)

As V says:

> Beneath this mask, there is more than flesh. Beneath this mask, there
>   is an idea, Mr Creedy. And idea's are bulletproof!

The book in fact has Evey carrying forward as V after his death, she dawn his mask so that the idea continues on via a new person.

Evey in the movie doesn't do that she instead explains to Finch:

> He was Edmond Dantès (V's favorite character). And he was my father. And my mother... my
>   brother... my friend. He was you, and me. He was all of us.

When people start taking off their masks we can see faces of characters new and those who have died. This is representative of the fact that everyone has in some small ways contributed to the change that they have brought about for themselves.

Comment: "Beneath this mask, there is more than flesh. Beneath this mask, there is an idea, Mr Creedy. And idea's are bulletproof!" Use more bullets.

Answer (score 5):

According to the film's [co-creator and illustrator David Lloyd](http://www.aintitcool.com/node/22672), the ending sequence was intended to show that the 'public' (res publica) are of one mind and body, rather than disconnected individuals. By having the people who chose to defy the State (and were killed by the State) shown at the end, the implication is that it's possible for the state to kill **a person**, but that they **can't kill the *idea* of freedom that those people were willing to die for**:

> **DAVID LLOYD:** *Well, I think because they stuck so close to the original
>   in the visual aspects of it... all the key instance scenes seemed like
>   they did them in that way and I think quite affectively. I
>   congratulate them the most, if you're asking me sort of about changes,
>   I congratulate them on the final part, on the ending. It was a very
>   clever idea of having all those people in the masks because basically
>   what it kind of symbolizes is an act of mass defiance, which is
>   actually a mass defiance made up of individuals because, of course, V
>   is representing the individuals' action. But the public adopting that
>   persona through the mask and **then becoming one... basically it was
>   like all for one and one for all.***
>
> *It was a very clever, symbolic way of doing everything.*

Comment: Nice. In general, I love the way the movie has been adapted from the book. The small changes really made it work for the film.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this out there for speculation and thought, what if they "ending" is what the people wanted to happen but never did and everyone wearing those masks had actually died from rioting against those troops. The track never started and Parliament was never destroyed. However, what the viewer sees is what everyone who rioted WANTED to see but never got the chance to. It would tie together the dead characters being in the crowd theory.

Comment: I don't think it was the case but that was an interesting Idea!

Answer (score -2):

In the scene where Evey Hammond and Inspector Eric Finch was watching in the distance as the Parliament building was being destroyed, Finch asked Evey who is V. Evey responded that he was you, and me, he was all of us. Now the mask symbolizes V and since he was "all of us" when they took off the mask they were, at that time, V.