# Who is the character 'V'?

Tags: character, v-for-vendetta

I have just watched the movie [**V for Vendetta**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0434409/), released in 2006.

In this movie, who is behind the mask? Is this character's real face shown in the film?

Comment: See also [Why was the killer's face never revealed in V for Vendetta (2005)?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/30486/566)

Answer (score 11):

**Who is V?**

From the wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(comics)) (my emphasis):

> **He is a mysterious anarchist, vigilante, and freedom fighter** who is
>   easily recognizable by his Guy Fawkes mask, long hair and dark
>   clothing. He strives to topple a totalitarian government of a
>   dystopian United Kingdom through grand acts of propaganda of the deed.
>   According to Moore, he was designed to be morally ambiguous, so that
>   readers could decide for themselves whether he was a hero fighting for
>   a cause or simply insane.

---

**Is his face shown?**

This is the closet you'll get to seeing his face:
[image: V emerging from the fire]

But you do get to see his hands:

[image: V's hands]